# Build Promotion SNAPSHOT to RELEASE

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I'm intentionally being a bit vague because I work for a big scary company - please let me know if more information would be helpful.

Using Artifactory and Jenkins here. (3.1.1 and 1.598 respectively.)

Creating snapshot builds works fine, build records are created and uploaded with the artifacts. However, we would like to save some of the snapshots as potential release candidates.

Attempting with the Build Promotion feature in Jenkins (Artifactory Release Promotion).

```
"level" : "WARNING",
"message" : "The repository 'libs-release-local' rejected the path [REDACTED] due to its snapshot/release handling policy."
```

Got similar errors promoting the build record using the REST API.

Looking through the build record, I can't find anything that says "SNAPSHOT" but the artifacts in question have that in their name - can I assume that the naming is the reason the artifacts are being declined?

Wondering if there is a proper way to do this (turn a snapshot into a release candidate) using the default tools, or if I'm stuck with one of those "write your own user plugin" answers.

Would the preferred "Best Practices" Java dev workflow just be to tag snapshot builds and checkout/rebuild when you want a releasable version of a specific snapshot? (Otherwise this would be core functionality, right?)

I did find this user plugin example:

https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins/blob/master/build/promotion.groovy

But I'm not 100% sure how it works since I don't do the groovy - I think it's actually copying the build record, renaming the associated artifacts, and publishing the whole mess as a "new" build. (?)

Thanks

Comment: I'm also looking to a similar workflow for my company. I'm not sure you can directly promote a SNAPSHOT build to a release repository. My idea is more to create a new kind of Artifactory repository (--> staging) and to publish Maven RELEASE binaries in this repo (sort of release candidate builds). When the QAs identified a staging build as stable, we can promote it in the release repository. I've not yet tested this solution, it's just an idea :)

Comment: So, the artifact has SNAPSHOT in the name, but the RC version is not snapshot, did I get you right?

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Yes, the artifact (.jar file) has "SNAPSHOT" in the name and was published to a snapshot repository. I would like to know the best way that I can mark it as not-a-snapshot and rename it to release it to QA, I guess.

Comment: Including metadata, that is.